# Why is there no (dict (k v)...) pattern in (match)?

Tags: pattern-matching, racket

beginner question here, i have only spent a few hours with the language.

Racket has [dictionaries](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/dicts.html), implemented by hash tables, lists of pairs, etc.  the `(match)` function recognizes `(hash-table (pat pat)...)`, `(list-no-order pat...)`, etc, but not `(dict (pat pat)...)`.

i thought it would be useful to pattern-match on the `dict` interface for the same reasons it's useful to have the interface at all.  its omission suggests that this is not the case.  can anyone tell me what i'm missing?  if i'd like to use `(match)` on data that could be either a hash or a list-of-pairs, should i have two clauses?  something else completely?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: nobody has felt the need strong enough to implement a `dict` pattern for `match`. Luckily `match` is extensible. The form `define-match-expander` can be used to extend the set of patterns that `match` can handle.

Let's say we want

```
(dict (k0 v0) (k1 v1))
```

to mean the same as

```
(or (hash-table (k0 v0) (k1 v1)
    (list-no-order (cons k0 v0) (cons k1 v1))
```

(and similar for patterns with more than two key-value pairs)
then we can define a match expander like this:

```
(define-match-expander dict
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_dict (key-pat val-pat) ...)
       #'(or (hash-table (key-pat val-pat)  ...)
             (list-no-order (cons key-pat val-pat) ...))])))
```

Now a pattern like `(dict ("a" a) ("b" b) ("c" c))` will be understood by `match`.

A full example:

```
#lang racket
(define-match-expander dict
  (λ (stx)
    (syntax-case stx ()
      [(_dict (key-pat val-pat) ...)
       #'(or (hash-table (key-pat val-pat)  ...)
             (list-no-order (cons key-pat val-pat) ...))])))

(define (keys+vals a-dict)
  (match a-dict
    [(dict ("a" a) ("b" b))
     (list a b)]))

(keys+vals (hash "a" 1 "b" 2))      ; gives '(1 2)
(keys+vals '(("b" . 5) ("a" . 4)))  ; gives '(4 5)
```